# Querying Active Directory via Java

Tags: java, powershell, active-directory

What is the best way to query Active Directory from Java?

Now I know that .NET has special methods built in for doing this sort of thing. But in Java, would calling a Powershell script by launching a process/command line be a good way of doing this?

Furthermore, why is the decision taken to call C# from Java anytime Java needs to access Windows WMI data? Is there a reason why running something like pstools (which can launch processes/commands on remote computers) from a command line called by Java, won't work?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the best way to query Active
>   Directory from Java?

I don't know if it is the **BEST** way, but the typical approach is to use LDAP. You can do this using JNDI. Examples of this can be found [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2000/jw-0324-ldap.html).

> Now I know that .NET has special
>   methods built in for doing this sort
>   of thing. But in Java, would calling a
>   Powershell script by launching a
>   process/command line be a good way of
>   doing this?

That depends. I think some java folks would cringe at this as it is a pretty clear violation of the "write once, run anywhere" type mentality. However, if you can guarantee that your app will only be used on windows and you have no other alternatives then I don't see the harm.

> Furthermore, why is the decision taken
>   to call C# from Java anytime Java
>   needs to access Windows WMI data? Is
>   there a reason why running something
>   like pstools (which can launch
>   processes/commands on remote
>   computers) from a command line called
>   by Java, won't work?

I'm not particularly sure I know the answer to this one. I think I'd need to see some clear examples to take a crack it it.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Please referred the following code.

```
package active.security.util.ldap;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;
//import javax.naming.ldap.PagedResultsControl;

import active.security.util.DateTool;


public class JNDISearch {
    public static String INITCTX = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"; // driver
    public static String MY_HOST = "ldap://dcserver:389"; // server and port
    public static String MY_SEARCHBASE = "DC=active,DC=local"; // base DC
    public static String MY_FILTER = "(&(objectclass=User)(!(objectclass=computer)))"; // filter
    public static String MGR_DN = "domain\\username"; // username
    public static String MGR_PW = "password"; // password
    public static String MY_ATTRS[] = {/* "cn","userpassword","mail", */"cn" };
    public static String temp = new String();

    public static void main(String[] ags) throws Exception{
        new JNDISearch().search();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public String search() throws Exception {

        int userCount = 0;
        Date begin = new Date();

        try {
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();

            //PagedResultsControl control = new PagedResultsControl(5000, true);
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITCTX);
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, MY_HOST);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, MGR_DN);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, MGR_PW);
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

            SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
            constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            NamingEnumeration results = ctx.search(MY_SEARCHBASE, MY_FILTER,constraints);

            while (results != null && results.hasMore()) {
                SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) results.next();
                // String dn = sr.getName();
                String dn = sr.getName() + "," + MY_SEARCHBASE;

                Attributes ar = ctx.getAttributes(dn, MY_ATTRS);
                if (ar == null) {
                    System.out.println("Entry " + dn
                            + " has none of the specified attributes\n");
                } else {
                    Attribute attr = ar.get("cn");
                    String cn = (String)attr.get(0);
                    System.out.println(cn);

                }
                userCount++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            Date end = new Date();

            long seconds = DateTool.getSenconds(begin, end);

            System.out.println("total user: "+userCount);
            System.out.println("time cost: "+seconds+" seconds");

        }

        return null;

    }


}
```

Comment: I found this quite useful. You can change the `MY_FILTER` value to "mail=<emailaddress>" to find out if the given <emailaddress> exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library. It's easy to use and powerfull

http://code.google.com/p/jedi-obi/

Comment: Horrible library (v2.3.0). Nearly no JavaDoc (existing are in French), miserable API, no information in error traces, few usage examples... Above all, it doesn't even simplify development by any considerable amount! I'll better be going pure LDAP.